# how can i Google + sign in in angular js

Tags: angularjs, web, sails.js

I am new in angular js. In the last few days i am trying to log in into my app using google account. Using html google+ button i have successfully done that using javascript. Bellow showing part of implemented code that is on simple (html+javascript).

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="389760997134-uredjv5rat0k3vsjaqlt7nn4pbgtqrat.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me">
  </span>
</span>
```

When trying that in angular i dont have any idea what what to do. Please give mw some idea what to do. I did not find anything clear over the internet. Any tutorial link or any partial project.

Comment: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/06/angularjs-google-sign-integration/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to implement google+ sign-in with angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809673/how-to-implement-google-sign-in-with-angularjs)